# Difference between window.ethereum and window.web3?

Tags: web3js, metamask

If I log the two functions, I get two objects, that both contain for example `selectedAddress`, but the structure of the objects seem different. I couldn't find  a comparison in the documentation.

I did find out that `window.web3.currentProvider`and `window.ethereum` are equal, but then, what is `window.web3` for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [Metamask API documentation](https://metamask.github.io/metamask-docs/API_Reference/Ethereum_Provider#api-reference):

> MetaMask injects a global API into websites visited by its users at
>   **window.ethereum** (**Also available at window.web3.currentProvider for
>   legacy reasons**). This API allows websites to request user login, load
>   data from blockchains the user has a connection to, and suggest the
>   user sign messages and transactions. You can use this API to detect
>   the user of a web3 browser.

---

**Edit:**

You can see what `window.web3` returns by opening a console in Chrome using "F12" (or whatever browser you're using), and typing `window.web3`:

```
> window.web3
Proxy {_requestManager: a, currentProvider: Proxy, eth: n, db: e.exports, shh: s, …}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: n
bzz: e.exports {_requestManager: a, blockNetworkRead: ƒ, syncEnabled: ƒ, swapEnabled: ƒ, download: ƒ, …}
currentProvider: Proxy {selectedAddress: undefined, networkVersion: "4", _events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: 100, …}
db: e.exports {_requestManager: a, putString: ƒ, getString: ƒ, putHex: ƒ, getHex: ƒ}
eth: n {_requestManager: a, getBalance: ƒ, getStorageAt: ƒ, getCode: ƒ, getBlock: ƒ, …}
net: e.exports {_requestManager: a, getListening: ƒ, getPeerCount: ƒ}
personal: e.exports {_requestManager: a, newAccount: ƒ, importRawKey: ƒ, unlockAccount: ƒ, ecRecover: ƒ, …}
providers: {HttpProvider: ƒ, IpcProvider: ƒ}
setProvider: ƒ ()
settings: e.exports {defaultBlock: "latest", defaultAccount: undefined}
shh: s {_requestManager: a, version: ƒ, info: ƒ, setMaxMessageSize: ƒ, setMinPoW: ƒ, …}
version: {api: "0.20.3", getNode: ƒ, getNetwork: ƒ, …}
_extend: ƒ (e)
_requestManager: a {provider: Proxy, polls: {…}, timeout: null}
__proto__: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

The same can be done for `window.ethereum`.

Comment: I read that before, but it doesn't say what exactly `window.web3` returns.

Comment: Edited my answer. Shout if that still doesn't help :-)

Comment: I'm logging pretty much every object and command to learn, and as I mentioned in the post (_"the structure of the objects seem different"_) I know what they look like, but I don't understand the purpose ob web3. Why the need for two different objects?

Comment: The answer is in the Metamask documentation I quoted above. The original API injected `window.web3.currentProvider`. There was an upgrade that introduced `window.ethereum`, which was slightly different to the old API. This is why they are different. `window.web3.currentProvider` still exists "for legacy reasons", i.e. because some people will still be using it in their code.

Comment: Then I rephrase my question to: what's the difference between `window.web3.currentProvider`and `window.web3`. And why isn't there `window.ethereum.currentProvider`? Does the old version offer more functionality?

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand what you're asking now :-) `window.web3.currentProvider` basically provided a subset of information relating to `window.web3`. By instantiating a `Web3()` object you would get access to everything. That same information is now available from `window.ethereum` (I think with some minor differences, hence the upgrade.) You can still get access to everything by instantiating `Web3()` in the same way (e.g. `window.web3 = new Web3(ethereum);` rather than `window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);`).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Sometimes it's not really made clear, why you should use a different class/object in a newer version, and seemingly, the objects injected by my metamask contained similar data, but I wasn't sure if they have slightly different purposes.

Comment: Okay, did a bit of digging around. This article might help detail the changes that were made when the API changed: https://medium.com/metamask/https-medium-com-metamask-breaking-change-injecting-web3-7722797916a8

Comment: I actually skimmed that post a few weeks ago... So then I assume the new object can preserve privacy much better.  It's interesting that `.currentProvider` isn't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2):

web3 is an older implementation that still some clients can use.

window.ethereum is new spec

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/8077